# Can not PUT file to google cloud storage bucket from JS in browser

Tags: javascript, python, cors, gcloud, digital-signature

I am using [google-cloud-storage](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) to generate a presigned URL to upload a file from the browser.

```py
BUCKET.cors = [
        {
            "origin": ["*"],
            "responseHeader": [
                "Content-Type",
                "x-goog-resumable"],
            "method": ['PUT', 'POST'],
            "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
        }
    ]
BUCKET.patch()

blob = BUCKET.blob(blob_name)

url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
        # Allow PUT requests using this URL.
        method="PUT",
        content_type="application/octet-stream",
)
```

The URL I get back looks like [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project-dev/edb5b48fcd724ab4a46afff3da5efa20/5b76eed38ed2473ea7c0b83e0e1d081c/52b675f15e2147849c911fe4f35951e9/60d98c630097eb435ad0991e_Frame%207-1.png?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=dev-laptop%40my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210910%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20210910T195738Z&X-Goog-Expires=900&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost&X-Goog-Signature=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). The `blob_name` I use is `"<UUID>/<UUID>/test.png"`.

I then `PUT` with `fetch` to the returned URL.

```js
  const {signed_url} = await(await fetch(baseUrl + "/upload/signed?blob_name=" + path, {
    credentials: "include",
  })).json();
  console.log('url', signed_url);
  // upload to google
  const url = await (await fetch(signed_url, {method: "PUT", body: file}) ).json()
```

**Two problems occur**

1. I get a CORS error - the PUT response does not include the `CORS-Allow-Origin: "*"` header.
2. When I bypass the first problem by using a [CORS plugin](https://mybrowseraddon.com/access-control-allow-origin.html) I get the following response:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
20210910T200720Z
20210910/auto/storage/goog4_request
3df68a505fbb635cc4092462461b715ad31b4e83db668726ca5d87ebe1d64d9a</StringToSign><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/my-project-dev/edb5b48fcd724ab4a46afff3da5efa20/5b76eed38ed2473ea7c0b83e0e1d081c/52b675f15e2147849c911fe4f35951e9/test.png
X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&amp;X-Goog-Credential=dev-laptop%40my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210910%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&amp;X-Goog-Date=20210910T200720Z&amp;X-Goog-Expires=900&amp;X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost
content-type:image/png
host:storage.googleapis.com

content-type;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest></Error>
```

I tried finding JS fetch examples on stackoverflow and the gcloud documentation site. I also checked if there is an option for the python library that I am missing. Now I am out of options. It seems that the storage buckets were not designed for this use case. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1976#issuecomment-278762945. As mentioned here, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls-v2?hl=ro#string-components, "As needed. If you provide a content-type, the client (browser) must provide this HTTP header set to the same value."

Comment: Yes, thank you. If you file an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mabel A. in the comments:

The problem was a mismatch of the content type in the creation of the PSL.

I needed to have content-type: `application/octet-stream` when uploading the file.